# how do you manipulate data to Json in ramdaJS

Tags: node.js, ramda.js

How do you convert Data to json file using RamdaJS
having a dynamic data, so you can re-use the code

input:

```
firstName,lastName,age,gender 
"Allan","Walter","23","M"
"Marry","Law","20","F"
"Zelda","Ham","25","F"
```

outupt:

```
[{
 firstName: "Allan",
 lastName: "Walter",
 age: "23",
 gender: "M"
},
{
 firstName: "Marry",
 lastName: "Law",
 age: "20",
 gender: "F"
},
{
 firstName: "Zelda",
 lastName: "Ham",
 age: "25",
 gender: "F"
}]
```

i was just wondering if its possible

Comment: Why "in Ramda"?  I'm one of Ramda's founders and a big fan, but I think of it as a library to be used where it's helpful, not as a framework that dictates how you write your code.

Comment: `ramda.js` has nothing to do with converting `csv` to `json`, so not sure what you're asking here.

Comment: We also seem to be missing your efforts.  Have you tried the problem yourself?  Are you stuck somewhere?

Comment: @B_B: editing the question -- even with fairly dramatic changes -- does not demonstrate any effort of your own to solve this. StackOverflow is designed around helping you with your own code when you get stuck, not around writing your code for you.  I think it might be an interesting problem to help with, but I'm not willing to put on the effort of you don't do so yourself.